# Value error when making a rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: python

I have just started programming in Python. I am currently trying to build a rock, paper, scissors game. The user is asked to pick a number representing one of the three options. Whereas the pc picks a random number. However, i get a value error for the input line. The same line worked fine in a different context (no while loop) but I fail to see what I did wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried to turn the string into a float and then into an integer. That did not work. Moreover, I have replaced the player input number y a random number to test the rest of the code. This worked just fine.

This is the error message I get:

```
answerplayer = int (input('What is your choice? ')) #Error
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "runfile
```

The code:

```
import random
win = False

while win == False:
    print ('Rock, Paper, Scissors. 0: Rock; 1: Scissors; 2: Paper')
    print ('Make your choice')
    answerplayer = int (input('What is your choice? ')) #Error
    answer = random.randrange (3)
    print (answerplayer)
    print (answer)
    if answer == 0 and answerplayer == 0 :
        print ('TIE')
    elif answer == 0 and answerplayer == 1 :
        print ('PC Win')
        win = True
    elif answer == 0 and answerplayer == 2 :
        print ('Player Win')
        win = True
    elif answer == 1 and answerplayer == 0 :
        print ('Player Win')
        win = True
    elif answer == 1 and answerplayer == 1 :
        print ('TIE')
    elif answer == 1 and answerplayer == 2 :
        print ('PC Win')
        win = True
    elif answer == 2 and answerplayer == 0 :
        print ('Player Win')
        win = True
    elif answer == 2 and answerplayer == 1 :
        print ('PC Win')
        win = True
    elif answer == 2 and answerplayer == 2 :
        print ('TIE')
    else:
        print ('Player Win')
        win = True

print ('done')
```

Comment: The error means that when the program asks for input, you aren't giving a valid integer.

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine. User input must be something that `int()` can convert to integer however.

Passes: `1` `2` `3.444`
Fails: `sqfe` `zero`

Answer (score 1):

you can solve with:

```
while win == False:
    print ('Rock, Paper, Scissors. 0: Rock; 1: Scissors; 2: Paper')
    print ('Make your choice')
    answerplayer = input('What is your choice? ')
    if not answerplayer.isnumeric() :
        print ('No number')
        break
    answerplayer = int(answerplayer)
    answer = random.randrange (3)
    print (answerplayer)
    print (answer)
```

Comment: Thanks guys, it's been fixed.